# SQL Server query where DATETIME

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I got this query:

```
select IDS as data 
from dbo.SKz 
where dbo.SKz.DatSave >= 2008-12-20
```

and it works OK. But when I want query by hours and minutes:

```
select IDS as data 
from dbo.SKz 
where dbo.SKz.DatSave >= 2008-12-20 23:59:59
```

I get an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '23'.

`DatSave` is a `datetime` column. Example from row = `2008-12-26 13:44:37.000`

Where is the problem? Thank you.

Comment: Missing quotes, `'2008-12-20 23:59:59'`

Comment: The first query doesn't work as you think it does... 2008-12-20 = 1976.

Comment: Thank you, with quotes it works :)

Comment: When inputting datetime values also check that your input format is language neutral. In this case you are ok. See this http://www.karaszi.com/SQLServer/info_datetime.asp#DtFormatsInput

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to put quotes around it.

```
select IDS as data from dbo.SKz WHERE dbo.SKz.DatSave>= '2008-12-20 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes.  However, I would strongly recommend one of the two following:

```
select IDS as data 
from dbo.SKz 
where dbo.SKz.DatSave >= '2008-12-21'
```

or:

```
select IDS as data 
from dbo.SKz 
where dbo.SKz.DatSave >= dateadd(day, 1, '2008-12-20')
```

I am guessing that you really do not want date/time values that are one second before midnight.